# Does somebody have experience with IRES and their coferences?

Tags: publications, conference

Recently I submited my research on this connference: http://theires.org/Conference2022/Canada/6/ICTTL/index.php
but after analysing some facts (eg. quick response from reviewer, lower price when paying earlier) it raised some red flags for me. So does anyone know have experience with IRES and there converences os maybe it is just a scam?

Best regards

Comment: This conference is ***definitely*** a scam. Just look at [this page of their website](http://theires.org/theires_conferences.php), they put on 20 conferences ***a day*** all over the world.

Comment: Early bird fee is not a red flag by itself, but this conference has many more. Stay away. @Ian not only that, they have like 20 completely unrelated ones in the same place (http://theires.org/conference.php?dt=2022-12&place=Kiev,Ukraine). "1427th International Conference" - what?! 3rd - okay, 20th - established, 1427th - outright ridiculous. At least I had a good laugh, too bad it had to be at the expense of the OP in a sense...